# Download CSV with Callback in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, python-requests

Trying to download a CSV from a button link in Morningstar. The link includes a callback, so it seems to be preventing the download. In Chrome, using the "inspect" feature, the URL is `http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&callback=?&t=XNAS:GOOGL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc`, but it doesn't auto download the CSV when pasted in the address bar. How can I update the below code to download the CSV from the link with a callback? `http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=GOOGL&region=usa&culture=en-US`

[image]

```
import requests

url = "http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&callback=?&t=XNAS:GOOGL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc"
with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(url)
    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)
    for row in my_list:
        print(row)

my_list
```

OUTPUT:

```
<Response [204]>
[]
```

Comment: The page is generated dynamically. You should use Selenium to download the data.

Comment: Is there any other way, using something more lightweight? https://www.codementor.io/codementorteam/how-to-scrape-an-ajax-website-using-python-qw8fuitvi

Comment: Why, give it a try.

Comment: Looking into it. Just don't see an ajax dict returned by minimizing the url lengths.

Comment: In the network tab, while inspecting the request (as depicted in the screenshot), if you were to click on the response tab, you'll notice that it doesn't return anything. Furthermore, it's not an `xhr` type, which means you can't expect to achieve the download through requests library. Selenium is pretty easy and fits your use case, please give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you do go down selenium route it is easy to use a class selector to target the download button. You can specify download options such as directory via chrome options.

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=GOOGL&region=usa&culture=en-US')
d.find_element_by_css_selector('.large_button').click()
d.quit()
```